# Android Gradle replace Package name for a value in manifest

Tags: android, gradle

I am using Gradle with Product flavors where I set a different package name for each one.

```
productFlavors {

    appone {
        packageName "com.dg.app1"
    }

    apptwo {
        packageName "com.dg.app2"
    }

    appthree {
        packageName "com.dg.app3"
    }

    appfour {
        packageName "com.dg.app4"
    }

}
```

I need to be able to replace the package name inside the manifest for each corresponding app.

My manifest has this:

```
<receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
          android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

    <category android:name="com.dg.example" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

So I need to replace com.dg.example for each app flavor's package name. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I don't know any way to "replace" the package name in the manifest at build time. But what about getting an AndroidManifest file for each flavor ?

Comment: I considered that but i will have to hardcode the package name everywhere, it will be my second choice if i cannot find a way to read the package name from build.gradle.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

**Gradle Plugin v0.12 and higher:**

Use `${applicationId}` instead of `${packageName}`.

**Gradle Plugin v0.11 and higher:**

As of v0.11, you no longer need to specify not to use the old manifest merger.

**Gradle Plugin v0.10 and higher:**

Assuming you're using version 0.10 or higher, this is now officially supported:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        // Make sure this is at least 0.10.+
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10.+'
    }
}
```

As of v0.10, you'll also have to manually enable the new [manifest merger](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger), although I'd expect that requirement to go away in a version or two whenever the new merger becomes the default:

```
android {
    useOldManifestMerger false
}
```

Then, just use `${packageName}` anywhere in `AndroidManifest.xml` that you would normally hardcode the package name. For example:

```
<category android:name="my.package.name"/>
```

would become

`<category android:name="${packageName}"/>`

---

**Gradle Plugin v0.9 and below:**

So, referencing [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/q1g7gAw0Lrc), it appears this is not yet officially supported through Gradle. A simple workaround is the following:

1. Replace the package name with a custom tag (e.g. `<category android:name="my.package.name"/>` becomes `<category android:name="_PACKAGENAME_"/>`
2. Add the following to your `build.gradle`, under the `android` scope:

---

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    // After processing the manifest, replace all instances of your tag
    // with the variant's actual package name.
    variant.processManifest << {
        def manifestOutFile = variant.processManifest.manifestOutputFile
        def newFileContents = manifestOutFile.getText('UTF-8').replace("_PACKAGENAME_", variant.packageName)
        manifestOutFile.write(newFileContents, 'UTF-8')
    }
}
```

Comment: Introducing custom tag produces errors kind of "package my.package.name does not exist". Using package name as is succeeded. BTW thank you for answer!

Comment: @M.Y. You shouldn't use the placeholder method in the actual packageName field -- that gets replaced automatically. Anyway, with 0.10 it should no longer be an issue anyway. :) Glad it helped.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know you could just use the variable, saves me some worries.

Comment: I tried this with ```<meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value="${packageName}.MainActivity"/>``` but it doesn't work.

Comment: @kcoppock but that would only work if both are the same.

Comment: @Alexander applicationId replaces packageName in recent versions of the Gradle plugin.

Comment: @kcoppock I know. But I want to refer to the package name (```<manifest package="xxx"```) and not to the application id.

Comment: @Alexander Ah I see. Unfortunately this currently doesn't work for that. Although, I believe you can just use `.MainActivity` and it'll auto-prefix the package name.

Comment: @kcoppock Nope. That was my first guess, too. I checked it on 4.0.3. ```.MainActivity``` didn't work.

Comment: starting with Android Studio 1.0 and android gradle plugin 1.0.0 it fails with "could not find property 'processManifest'"

Answer (score 3):

To do something like this, I use buildTypes in my gradle file but I am pretty sure this will work with flavours as well. For me I am trying to set the label field in the activities.

I have a strings xml file for each of my buildTypes. 
Then I have a sourceSet for each buildType which includes the correct strings file.
Then in the manifest I do not use a hard coded string but rather "@string/my_var" which will pull the correct string depending on how the sourceSets are defined.

This [google+ post](https://plus.google.com/118417777153109946393/posts/WRgB2shaeuu) and [related gist](https://gist.github.com/cyrilmottier/8234960) may help.

Something else to do is to put a AndroidManifest.xml file into the src/flavour which only contains the bits which are relevant to each flavour. Then take those bits out of the main manifest file. At build time the Manifest files will be merged into one file. You can see the result all of the merged manifests in build/manifests.

Comment: Also something to note, the packageName only changes the identification in the Manifest file but not the actual java package hierarchy. So in my builds things have different package names so that they are identified correctly on play but in the code it is still using the same package name for the classes etc.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and implemented a placeholder replace method in Gradle. It does exactly what you'd expect but also takes care about `packageNameSuffix` attributes so you can have `debug` and `release` as well as any other custom builds on the same device.

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def flavor = variant.productFlavors.get(0)
    def buildType = variant.buildType
    variant.processManifest.doLast {
        println '################# Adding Package Names to Manifest #######################'
        replaceInManifest(variant,
            'PACKAGE_NAME',
            [flavor.packageName, buildType.packageNameSuffix].findAll().join()) // ignores null
    }
}

def replaceInManifest(variant, fromString, toString) {
    def flavor = variant.productFlavors.get(0)
    def buildtype = variant.buildType
    def manifestFile = "$buildDir/manifests/${flavor.name}/${buildtype.name}/AndroidManifest.xml"
    def updatedContent = new File(manifestFile).getText('UTF-8').replaceAll(fromString, toString)
    new File(manifestFile).write(updatedContent, 'UTF-8')
}
```

I have it up on a [`gist`](https://gist.github.com/saadfarooq/9651367) too if you want to see if it evolves later.

I found to be a more elegant approach than the multiple resources and XML parsing approaches.

Answer (score 0):

### Option Gradle:

Use grade [attributes](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/java/archives/Manifest.html#attributes%28java.util.Map%29) API. Some thing like this

```
manifest.attributes(["attr1":"value1", "attr2":"value2"])
```

### Option 1

How about converting your project to Android - library project, and making extra project for each company. Than you can edit the `Manifest` file as you wish.

### Option 2

Write a batch file.

Comment: No it should be a simple string replacement. i don't want to restructure the whole project hierarchy not to use Gradle. Even with Gradle i can completely replace the manifest file.

Comment: @DArkO What is your laziness level considering option 2?

Comment: I want to do it with Gradle, What you are suggesting is working around a build system that is meant to do these things.

Comment: @DArkO I just been looking at Gradle. Before saw it before. Looks cool. How about the Gradle option?