# Build script error, unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'useOldManifestMerger()'!

Tags: android, gradle

My build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
        mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"
    useOldManifestMerger false
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Without line `useOldManifestMerger false` it builds ok.
gradle version: 1.10.
gradle android plugin: don't know where to look.
I think it is trying to use pre 0.10 of gradle android plugin. How can I reinstall it?

Comment: You can check which version of the plugin you have by declaring a task like this: 
task showClasspath << {
    buildscript.configurations.classpath.each { println it.name }
}

Comment: Thanks @PerrynFowler, will update question later.

Comment: For now, I ended up using this workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109019/android-gradle-replace-package-name-for-a-value-in-manifest