# Using build types in Gradle libraries to run same app that uses ContentProvider on one device

Tags: android, gradle, android-contentprovider, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I'm having the issue where my Android Content Provider is not being recognized in a separate build variant from an Android library. I've followed most of the ideas in: [Using build types in Gradle to run same app that uses ContentProvider on one device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16777534/using-build-types-in-gradle-to-run-same-app-that-uses-contentprovider-on-one-dev#)

I also followed: http://www.kevinrschultz.com/blog/2014/03/23/using-android-content-providers-with-multiple-package-names/

When I try running the app, the parent application tries to import a java class from the FYC library listed in **src/main/AndroidManifest.xml** and doesn't recognize the class because of the .qa package name?

My library FYC.gradle file looks like this:

```
...
android
{
    ...
    productFlavors
    {
        prod {
           packageName "com.company.android"
        }

        qa {
           packageName "com.company.android.qa"
        }
    }
}
```

I commented out the content provider in main:
**src/main/AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.company.android.fyc"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<!--<provider-->
            <!--android:name=".models.listing.ListingProvider"-->
            <!--android:authorities="com.company.android.fyc.models.listing.listingprovider"-->
            <!--android:exported="false" />-->

</manifest>
```

**src/prod/AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.company.android.fyc"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1">

    <application>

        <provider
            android:name=".models.listing.ListingProvider"
            android:authorities="com.company.android.fyc.models.listing.listingprovider"
            android:exported="false" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```

**src/qa/AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.company.android.fyc"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1">

    <application>

        <provider
        android:name=".models.listing.ListingProvider"
        android:authorities="com.company.android.qa.fyc.models.listing.listingprovider"
        android:exported="false" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```

I tried another option and tried using a variable for the package name, but Gradle gave me an error that it didn't recognize $?

In AndroidManifest.xml, you can use ${packageName} like this:

```
    <!--<provider-->
        <!--android:name=".models.listing.ListingProvider"-->
        <!--android:authorities="${packageName}.fyc.models.listing.listingprovider"-->
        <!--android:exported="false" />-->
```

Does anyone have another recent work around for this issue? Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109019/android-gradle-replace-package-name-for-a-value-in-manifest - this looks like it could solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for the link to the other question, as I think that's the real issue I'm having. This is still an issue because when I add a build variant in the child library, the parent library can't find the java class from the child library because the package name has changed.