# Android Gradle product flavor fails in child library

Tags: android, gradle, android-library, android-productflavors

This issue should solve my other issue where I need to update the child libraries content provider: [Using build types in Gradle libraries to run same app that uses ContentProvider on one device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644274/using-build-types-in-gradle-libraries-to-run-same-app-that-uses-contentprovider)

I have a product flavor in the root application that is successfully changing the package name so I can deploy different versions of the app. When I try to add the same product flavor in a child library, the build fails because the root application fails to load a java class that is referenced from the child library because now the package name has changed? I thought that product flavors did not effect the java class package structure?

**ATCApp.gradle root application**

```
...
dependencies {
...
compile project(':libraries:FYC')
...
}

...
android
{
    ...
    productFlavors
    {
        prod {
           packageName "com.company.android"
        }

        qa {
           packageName "com.company.android.qa"
        }
    }
}
```

**FYC.gradle child library**

```
...
android
{
    ...
    productFlavors
    {
        prod {
           resValue "string", "authority", "com.company.android.fyc.models.listing.listingprovider"
        }

        qa {
           resValue "string", "authority", "com.company.android.qa.fyc.models.listing.listingprovider"
        }
    }
}
```

Adding the above product flavors in the child FYC library causes the root application to throw an error:

**/src/main/java/com/company/android/HomeBroadcastReceiver.java:7: package com.company.android.fyc.controllers does not exist
import com.company.android.fyc.controllers.FYCHomePagerActivity;**

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can't do dependencies on flavors (aka, chained flavors), as Gradle offers no way to express such a thing.  Your root project can have [different dependencies based on the flavor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589342/add-dependency-to-specific-productflavor-and-buildtype-in-gradle), but those dependencies cannot be explicit flavors themselves.  The output of sub-projects should be predictable and consistent.

Comment: Wow, that's bad, because then I can't adjust the content provider based on the product flavor and I'll have to manually change the content provider whenever I need a new QA build.

Comment: I'm sure you can extract the flavor-specific logic into your parent project, and pass it into your library project.

Comment: It goes back to solving my original issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644274/using-build-types-in-gradle-libraries-to-run-same-app-that-uses-contentprovider. I have a contentprovider in the library project, but when I run the QA version of the app, I have to change the package name of the provider.