# Android Manifest Cannot be Edited

Tags: android

I am new in android development. I am using the Android Studio 1.5.1 to create a registration form. I am at the manifest.xml creation step. I know how to code it, but when I go to my library and open the automatic generated manifest file, I cannot edit it. It has a bunch of symbols that cannot be deleted.

They look like

> �  �    X  �  �  T  �    @  �  �  *  r  �    N  �
>   �  2  |  �  B  �  �  R  �  "  h  �  �  :  �  �  R  �
>     h  �     @  z  �    z  �  L  �  ,  x  �  2  �  �
>   8   �    !  n!  �!  2"  �"  �"  N#  �#  4$  �$  %  t%  �%  v&  �&  �'
>   (  �(  )  p)  �)  d*  �*  h+  �+  n,  -  �-  .  �.  �.  p/  �/  N0
>   �0  �0  >1  �1  �1  2  V2  �2  �2  T3  �3  �3  t4  �4  5  �5  �5  J6
>   �6  �6  &7  l7  �7  8  \8  �8  �8  Z9  �9  �9  >:  �:  �:  ;  `;  �;
>   <  J<  �<  �<  8=  �=  �=  J>  �>  �>  H?  �?   @  \@  �@  �@  HA  �A
>   �A  4B  �B  "C  �C  �C  DD  �D  �D  4E  rE  �E  �E  HF  �F   G  TG  �G
>   �G  JH  �H  �H  NI  �I  �I  HJ  �J   K  hK  �K  HL  �L  �L  TM  �M  N
>   xN  �N  O  \O  �O  �O  ,P  nP  �P   Q  �Q  R  hR  �R  6S  �S  T  �T
>   U  �U  V  lV  �V  PW  �W  X  jX  �X  �X  Y  ^Y  �Y  �Y  .Z  jZ  �Z
>   �Z  [  h[  �[  �[  >\  �\  �\  .]  �]  �]  ^`^  �^  �^  :_  �_  �_
>   `n`  �`�`

Can I find some helping creating the manifest file on Android Studio?

Comment: Encoding hell! Scary...by the way you missed escaping some characters when pasting...

Comment: It should be plain text and readable. Gradle can insert stuff into the manifest this link kinda talks about it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109019/android-gradle-replace-package-name-for-a-value-in-manifest maybe its French?